# Error on Apply lambda function to multiple columns pandas

Tags: lambda, keyerror

I'm looking to include multiple columns in a lambda function on the following df:

```
target_df.columns
Index(['Surname', 'Name', 'Sex', 'BirthDate', 'BirthPlace', 'FiscalCode'], dtype='object')
```

but is seems do not recognize a column name:

```
target_df['FiscalCode'] = target_df.apply(lambda x: codicefiscale.encode(x['Surname'], x['Name'], x['Sex'], x['BirthDate'], x['BirthPlace']))
target_df

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897             try:
-> 2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: 'Surname'
...
   2902         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'Surname'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

```
target_df['FiscalCode'] = target_df.apply(lambda x: codicefiscale.encode(x["Surname"], x["Name"], x["Sex"], x["BirthDate"], x["BirthPlace"]), axis=1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).